# Faster way to multiply in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at ways to multiply faster in JavaScript, and I found this

https://medium.com/@p_arithmetic/4-more-javascript-hacks-to-make-your-javascript-faster-1f5fd88a219e#.306ophng2

which has this text

```
Instead of multiplying, use the bit shift operation. it looks a little more complex, but once you get the hang of it, it’s pretty simple. The formula to multiply x * y is simply x << (y-1)

As a bonus, everyone else will think you’re really smart!

// multiply by 1
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(n){ return n<<0; }) // 1,2,3,4
// multiply by 2
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(n){ return n<<1; }) // 2,4,6,8
// multiply by 3
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(n){ return n<<2; }) // 3,6,9,12
// etc
```

However this doesn't seem to work for me. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I've heard that it's better to avoid bitwise operators.

Comment: I'd consider `x << (y - 1)` slower than `x * y` due to the operators overhead (`<<` and `-` together). And it doesn't work with doubles ee

Comment: The author of that article is intentionally trolling, it's meant to be a joke.

Comment: It's a fake article, don't listen to him

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore that article. It's intended as humor -- the advice it's giving is intentionally terrible and wrong.

1. Multiplication does not involve "expensive logarithmic look up tables and extremely lucky guesses" with "dozens of guesses per second". It is a highly optimized hardware operation, and any modern CPU can perform *hundreds of millions* (or more!) of these operations per second.
2. Bitwise operations are not faster than multiplication in Javascript. In fact, they're much slower -- numbers are generally stored as double-precision floating point by default, so performing a bitwise operation requires them to be converted to integers, then back.
3. Bit-shifting is not equivalent to multiplication in the way that the article implies. While left-shifting by 0 and 1 are equivalent to multiplication by 1 and 2, the pattern continues with `<<2` and `<<3` being equivalent to a multiplication by **4 and 8**, not 3 and 4.
4. `Array.forEach` does not return a value. The appropriate function to use here would be `Array.map`.

The other "Javascript hacks" described in the article are even worse. I won't bother going into details.

Comment: Oops! This isn't an answer.

Comment: @handoncloud I've added some further explanation -- but the article is, simply put, trolling. This is far more of an explanation than it deserves.

Comment: It's important fake articles like that are exposed. Javascript is complex enough for newbies without trolls like these. Humans... :/

Comment: "Bitwise operations are not faster than multiplication in Javascript. In fact, they're much slower" - Really? Optimized engines store integers as such and only convert to double when necessary. Computations within integer range thus should not involve type conversions and guarantee that shifting is much faster than multiplying.

Comment: I have just tested multiplying bigints and doing a left-shift was 60% faster. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

Incidentally, if you want to know why it isn't working for you, you will want to use `map` instead of `forEach` since `forEach` ignores the return.

So do this instead:

```
// multiply by 1
[1,2,3,4].map(function(n){ return n<<0; }) // 1,2,3,4
// multiply by 2
[1,2,3,4].map(function(n){ return n<<1; }) // 2,4,6,8
// multiply by 4
[1,2,3,4].map(function(n){ return n<<2; }) // 4,8,12,16
// multiply by 8
[1,2,3,4].map(function(n){ return n<<3; })  // 8, 16, 24, 32
```

And as others have mentioned - don't use this for multiplication. Just take this as a clarity of forEach vs map...

Comment: please.. it's a fake article, let's not support this kinda thing

Comment: Agreed. Just giving the OP an answer to why it wasn't working for him. I would definitely not endorse using this for multiplication it is obscure, hiding the intent in 'clever coding'.

Answer (score -2):

Bit shift is not the same as multiplying by any number. This is how bit shift works in decimal for example:

```
1234 >> 0 = 1234
1234 >> 1 = 0123 #discards the last digit.
0123 >> 2 = 0001 #discards the last two digit
```

So in decimal, shifting digits to the right is like integer division by 10. When shifted by two digits it's the same as dividing by 10^2.

Now computers work with binary words. So instead of a digit shift, we have bit shifts.

```
10101011 >> 1 = 01010101
```

This is basically dividing by 2^1.

`10101011 >> n` is simply dividing by 2^n.
Now in the same manner,
`10101011 << n` is multiplying by by 2^n. This adds n zeroes behind the binary word.

Hope it's clearer now :)

Cheers